# can't open static page in intellij after run the project(spring mvc)

Tags: java, web, intellij-idea, static-pages

In the beginning, I can view the html just by the IntelliJ button like that

[image]

then when I click the button, IntelliJ shows a browser error

[image]

then I run tomcat, and click the browser button

[image]

I'm a beginner, and I don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run servlet container via Run configuration first.